# Ensuring a const (readonly) object's keys conform to a const (readonly) array of values or type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Let's say I  have an object that I want to make sure its keys conform to another type. I'm creating a dictionary of mapped keys, where on the left I have the original, and on the right, the displayed key. I need this available in both runtime and compile time, so doing this as `const` objects and arrays seems to make sense?

(Yes, I tried doing this with an array of tuples, but TypeScript is mad at me now).

```
const allowedKeys = ["cheese_type", "jalapeno_qty", "pepperoni"] as const;

const keyMap = {
   cheese_type:  "Cheese type",
   jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños",
   pepperoni: "Pepperoni",
} as const;
```

This gives me a type that has all the keys mapped out explicitly:

```
const keyMap: {
    readonly cheese_type: "Cheese type";
    readonly jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños";
    readonly pepperoni: "Pepperoni";
}
```

(I can export the types, too)

```
export const Keys = typeof allowedKeys
export const KeyMap = typeof keyMap
```

But I also want to protect the `keyMap` from accidentally misspelling or adding keys that it shouldn't have, so I want to make it conform to the `allowedKeys` array.

But if I do that, I can't figure out how to infer or define the object values as readonly/const properties...

```
const allowedKeys = ["cheese_type", "jalapeno_qty", "pepperoni"] as const;
type Keys = typeof allowedKeys;

const keyMap: {
  [key in Keys]: string // oh no
} = {
   cheese_type:  "Cheese type",
   jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños",
   pepperoni: "Pepperoni",
} as const;
```

Is there any way I can do this that doesn't make me run into crazy cycles like:

```
const keyMap: {
  [key in Keys]: key in keyMap ? keyMap[key] : never; // haha no
} = {
   cheese_type:  "Cheese type",
   jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños",
   pepperoni: "Pepperoni",
} as const;
```

(Ultimately, I want to be able to have two sets of keys I can reference...)

```
export type RawKey = typeof keyMap;
export type DisplayKey = ValueOf<typeof keyMap>;
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2289w) using the `satisfies` operator meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz fantastic! Completely omitted `satisfies` from my brain thing.  Also works with my other need for it, `type RawKeys = keyof typeof keyMap;
type DisplayKeys = ValueOf<typeof keyMap>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to check that a value matches a particular type without widening it to that type which can throw away information you want.

So as long as you have the type `Keys` of the keys you want to allow:

```
const allowedKeys = ["cheese_type", "jalapeno_qty", "pepperoni"] as const;
type Keys = typeof allowedKeys[number];
```

You can say that `keyMap` `satisfies Record<Keys, string>`:

```
const keyMap = {
    cheese_type: "Cheese type",
    jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños",
    pepperoni: "Pepperoni",
} as const satisfies Record<Keys, string>;
```

and then `keyMap` still remembers all the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of its properties:

```
/* const keyMap: {
    readonly cheese_type: "Cheese type";
    readonly jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños";
    readonly pepperoni: "Pepperoni";
} */
```

And if you make mistakes with `keyMap`, the compiler should catch them:

```
const extraKeyMap = {
    cheese_type: "Cheese type",
    jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños",
    pepperoni: "Pepperoni",
    pineapple: "⁉" // error!
} as const satisfies Record<Keys, string>;

const missingKeyMap = {
    cheese_type: "Cheese type",
    pepperoni: "Pepperoni",
} as const satisfies Record<Keys, string>; // error!

const misspelledKeyMap = {
    cheese_type: "Cheese type",
    jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños",
    peppperroni: "Preppypony", // error!
} as const satisfies Record<Keys, string>;
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
    const allowedKeys = ["cheese_type", "jalapeno_qty", "pepperoni"] as const;
    type Keys = typeof allowedKeys;
    const keyMap: Record<Keys[number], string> = {
        cheese_type:  "Cheese type",
        jalapeno_qty: "Number of jalapeños",
        pepperoni: "Pepperoni"
    } as const;
```

This will prevent additional keys from being added to the `keyMap`.

EDIT:
In regards to pinks comment, you can do

```
const keyMap: Readonly<Record<Keys[number], string>> = ...
```

to make the `keyMap` readonly.

Comment: One major downside is that `keyMap` is no longer readonly and now it's values are typed as `string` instead of being literal types.

Comment: Yup, exactly. Unfortunately this creates `const keyMap: Record<"cheese_type" | "jalapeno_qty" | "pepperoni", string>`, which no longer has the key: value map pairing either.